# ArcGIS | Creating layers and markers

Tags: c#, arcgis

I am making a program that manages archaeological data, and a part of it is creating new layer and markers for their findings.
I am using ArcGIS Engine with visual studio 2010 (C#) to make a stand alone program.

I read the documentation about Arcgis engine, but i haven't found a way to create markers that will appear on the TOC control and will be categorized in layers I have created as well.

Is there a way to create new layers and new markers in them (that will appear on the TOC) through the code?

Thank you

Comment: By "categorized in layers I have created", do you mean you want to add multiple layers, or add one layer and set the markers to have different symbols based on their properties?

The former is trivial, the latter involves an UniqueValueRenderer: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000rrq000000 .